# Jquery target specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Hi is thee any way I can target only this specific Element and add : right:10px;

[image]

I need the exact code, if that's possible. Thank you

Comment: *I need the exact code, if that's possible.* we need it first, from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$('input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit.btn.btn-info.btn-large').css({'right':'10px'})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I don't want to affect other elements with the same class, is there any way to affect only this one?

Comment: that's why I added as much classes as possible

Comment: @Flamur: that's why in my answer i gave only the wpcf7-submit class

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. submit button has class `wpcf7-submit`. you can use class selector to target it:

```
$('.wpcf7-submit').css('right','10px');
```

Comment: Assuming that class is only used once...of course!

Comment: indeed yes. class has submit in it.

Comment: Ok...must be a WP / widget thing.

Comment: yeah. also it can be for wordpress too. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-types-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-management-wpcf-on-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

use its unique class name,I have assumed that class `wpcf7-submit` is only used once

```
$('input.wpcf7-submit').css({'right':'10px'});
```